# error when making a kernel My toolchain always says "no such file or directory"

Tags: kernel

So I am trying to make an old kernel on the newest Unbuntu. Set up build essentials libncurses5-dev bzip2 cant get kernel-package says its unavailable? Haven't found an alternate source. Ive gotten all the sources an set up Unbuntu im following this guide: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/ultimate-guide-noob-friendly-compile-your-own-android-kernel-from-source.2871276/
When I export
export CROSS_COMPILE=~/android/kernel/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin/arm-eabi-
No problem  when I can set up my defconfig I can do that and I can enter menuconfig, but when I go to compile I get

make: /home/c/android/kernel/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin/arm-eabi-gcc: No such file or directory

/home/c/kernel/scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 25: /home/c/android/kernel/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin/arm-eabi-gcc: No such file or directory

/home/c/kernel/scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 26: /home/c/android/kernel/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin/arm-eabi-gcc: No such file or directory

Im using this kernel source https://github.com/DooMLoRD/Xperia-2011-Kernel-2.6.32.9/tree/master/kernel

Is there something I need to modify in the source to get it to find the toolchain? I've copy pasted the location of the toolchain when I export to make sure there is no error so that cant be the issue. Then I copy pasted the path from the error and ls and its definitely there. So I'm very confused.

Comment: This site is for *users* of Android, which means that questions about development/programming are off-topic here (see the [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic)). Development questions are on-topic on our sister site [Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android). You might also wish to consult [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](//android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) for a fitting place to your question.

Comment: @Izzy So your telling me as and android “enthusiast user” you’ve never used Roms or compiled kernels ? Interesting so this is for users of the system is it for people who flash Roms as well? Just no compiling questions ?

Comment: Right. It's for users (including "power users") – but questions concerning development (including compilation issues) are off-topic. Just follow the links for details. As you quote XDA as the source of your guide: that would be the place I'd recommend you direct your question to, as those are the folks who should know best.

Comment: @izzy thankyou but that device generation is no longer monitored by anyone who would know I thought of using the normal stack exchange but they seem to get pissed about android linux questions unless its app development. I did eventually get it sorted on my own though.

Comment: Glad to read you got it solved! And be welcome here with (user-focused) questions on Android :)